# sonar custom rule check java collection type is unknownSymbol

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonar-runner, sonarlint

Collection type always return 'unknownSymbol' in a custom sonar check rule class.

//demo class

```
public class SaasConstantNameCheckCase {
    private static final long serialVersionUID;
    private final String title;
    public static final Integer maxSize = 1111;// Noncompliant
    private static List list = new ArrayList<>();
    private static HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
}
```

// custom rule class

```
@Override
public void visitVariable(VariableTree tree) {
    VariableSymbol symbol = (VariableSymbol) tree.symbol();
    String type = symbol.type().name();
    System.out.println("type->"+type);
}
```

// test result

```
type->long
type->String
type->Integer
type->!unknownSymbol!
type->!unknownSymbol!
```

Why?

Comment: Is your sample source code complete? This looks to me like a type resolution issue, and I don't see the "import" statements for List or HashMap.

Comment: @Mithfindel I am so stupid, forget to import...

Comment: No need for self-bashing, I think it's an honest mistake :) If you don't mind, I'll post an answer to document this issue - IMHO it is quite common.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SonarJava will show this `unknownSymbol!` string when it fails to resolve the actual type symbols.

In this particular case, you should either use fully qualified types `java.util.List` and `java.util.HashMap`, or import them.